# Which is better for repeatedly opening multiple forms in WPF app - hiding them or closing them?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, forms, memory

I have main window A, from which you can open non-modal forms X, Y and Z. Should you open form X and try to open it again, it will simply be brought to the front. Once you close form X, you should be able to open it again. 
(Exactly like the way you use the "Find" window in MS Word)

What will be the least memory and resource intensive - closing Form X and creating a new instance of it each time it is pressed, or hiding Form X and making it visible when the user tries to open it?

There will be a number of forms for things like editing settings, adding clients etc. Not all will be opened in a session, some will only be used once, some will be used many times in one session of the program being open.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is off topic for this website as it is primarily opinion based, but in short hiding/showing is *much* quicker than closing/re-opening. The only downside is that window resources are held while a window is hidden, but depending on the window, this really should be negligible.

Answer (score 2):

Showing and hiding forms is faster, because you don't need to recreate controls every time. Virtualization in WPF is almost exactly that — controls are reused by adding and removing them from the control tree, data contexts are changed.

However, while showing and hiding is faster, resource management is harder: the form will likely hold references to your models, so if they're heavy you'll need to work with memory management more. Controls are unlikely to consume lots of memory (you can fix that using virtualization and other techniques), so it's not the source of the problem.

When in doubt, measure. Recreating forms is easier, so do this by default. If it's slow (for example, if there're hundreds of controls), try optimizing and *measuring* preformance gains. On slow devices, this optimization can make a big difference.